# Is dynamic reloading disabled by default in GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.2?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I was just reading a documentation called 'The Java EE 7 Tutorial' from Oracle.

One line says "In GlassFish Server, dynamic reloading is enabled by default.", so I wanted to disable dynamic reloading in the Administration Console because it causes performance degradation.

I found an article on how to disable dynamic reloading in glassfish server. The instruction says "Select the GlassFish Server node." and "Select the Advanced tab.". However, there is no advanced tab to select.

So I was wondering if glassfish server removed the option of dynamic reloading by making it disabled by default.

If it is enabled by default like the doc says, can someone tell me how to disable it in the Administration Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my glassfish, is still enabled by default but is in

Domain->Applications Configuration (tab)-> Auto Deploy.

[image]

Comment: I think it should be `Domain->Applications Configuration (tab)->Reload`, but this page is exactly what I was looking for. I just unchecked the `Enabled` next to `Reload`. Thank you.